# Office 365 out of office assistant

Tags: windows, exchange, microsoft-office-365

We have Office365 and Exchange 2010 SP1 in a Hybrid setup.

Most of the users in the cloud have the Out Of Office Assistant working fine. However, there is at least one user that is not working (that is hosted on the cloud).

The out of office assistant doesn't work internally or externally for that user. The user is able to set it up normally, but when external or internal users sent emails to this user there is no out of office automatic reply sent.

I have already checked [Out of office assistance not working externally](https://serverfault.com/questions/24742/out-of-office-assistance-not-working-externally), http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/158/p/63862/244004.aspx#244004 and http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/158/t/53858.aspx?PageIndex=2.

Everything seems fine. The user is not forwarding emails to another mailbox, and there doesn't seem to be anything special about the user. Not sure how to troubleshoot.

When using the PS Session to the cloud the Get-Mailbox 'affected mailbox name' | Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration looks correct.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: What's not working.  You haven't described what about it is not working. More detail please.

Comment: The out of office automatic responses are not sent. Added it to the description - hopefully it is clear now. Thanks. BTW: I am willing to add any additional detail - just not sure what details are relevant :(

Comment: Delete user and recreate?  What I'd probably do on a non-cloud account, don't know if that's helpful or feasible for you.

Comment: Hopefully that can be avoided. We are talking about one user with a +9gb mailbox, multiple permissions in the network, etc.

Comment: When you say the user is not forwarding - do you mean that user has no rules set up to forward, or that there is no forwarding configured in the mailbox settings? The `Get-Mailbox 'affected' | fl` should show the `DeliverToMailboxAndForward` and `ForwardingAddress` attributes.

Comment: @john: DeliverToMailboxAndForward= false. ForwardingAddress= (blank). I just checked (and I still have the issue - sadly, it is my own user account). Thanks.

Comment: @rufo - OK, umm... Have you checked the delivery reports to see if O365 is even attempting to send the mail?

Comment: @john: no, that hasn't occurred to me. My normal emails work fine. I will try to check on this.

Comment: Are they setting the Out of Office Assistant from the web client, or from within Outlook?

Comment: @woodsbw: from both places. Neither one seems to work.

Comment: I know we have has issues where it will not work properly when set within Outlook...never had it fail from the web client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a case with Microsoft. They connected to my computer and had me 2 hours going back and forth doing tests (they were very polite, and tried to help).

Their suggestions are the same above. That didn't help. However, they thought that my profile having too many rules (+100) might have something to do.

Offline I cleaned up my rules, deleting a lot of rules that I had disabled (~20 rules). That fixed the issue.

It seems that some rule was corrupted, or my total rules count didn't allow Exchange to add the rule for the automatic reply. In any case, my situation is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Problems are in roules. Clear roules and it will work fine to end user. I had that same problem.
I really don't understand why do you need 100+ roules.

y clent had same problem, but I deleted "cloud" user and recreated the account and it worked fine. Of course, you need to backup data before deleting user. He was in P1 plan and didn't use SharePoint.

Comment: Yes, that is explained in the answer (from me on Feb 11). BTW: I do not think my need for +100 rules have to be justified: if Outlook allows me to create them they should work. Anyways: I manage many systems - I get *many* automated emails that I classify using rules. Thanks.

Comment: -1, we don't like "me too" answers.  Espeically poorly written, "me too" answers.